# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This is weird, I have used [*UpdateSingleSalesforceObject*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) AMPScript function multiple times but at times it behaves rather strange and I have observed this twice now.
The following piece of AMPScript code was working fine until Friday:

```
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Shared_Contact_In_Scope__c", "a8e0x0000008ONyAAM","Shared_Contact_Status__c", "Attended")
```

However, since last two days, all my cloud pages which are using this function are giving following error:

[image: Error in cloud pages]

Has anyone faced such issue?

Comment: sure you don't have a comma out of place or some other typo somewhere else?

Comment: No @garek007, I opened a case with SFMC support and they are still working on it. This code started working on Monday without any changes. Seems some issue during the weekend. I shall update my comments here when I hear from Support about what exactly happened (if they come up with something :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @victorcorey: Yes, the support confirmed that they had connector issues which caused this..... it started working on its own on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

The support confirmed that they had some connector issues which causes all connector related functionality to break and hence this was causing 500 error. Everything is working fine now without any changes.